# Cannot parse file with mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Why in mocha my parser returns an error, but in vanilla JS it works well? This is my parser that I keep in a separate file, it should parse CSV file and extract value from there.

**parser.js:**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = async function(num) {
    const response = await fetch('../date.csv');
    const data = await response.text();
    let rows = data.split('\n');
    let res = rows[0].split(',');
    return res[num];
}
```

**date.csv file:**

```
1,?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-09-05,SomeInfo,false
2,?start=2014-09-01&end=2014-09-05,SomeInfo,false
```

**Mocha test:**

```
let file = require('../utils/parser');
let param = file(1);

describe('Account', () => {
    it('Print', () => {
        console.log(param);
       });
   });
```

**Logs:**

```
Account
Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
      at getNodeRequestOptions (node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1305:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide an absolute url to the file.

For example, before starting the tests, set some environment variable so that it points to the root url of your server:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8080' mocha"
  ...
}
```

And then in the code do something like this:

**parser.js**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = async function(num) {
    const absPath = process.env.BASE_URL + '../date.csv'
    const response = await fetch(absPath);
    const data = await response.text();
    let rows = data.split('\n');
    let res = rows[0].split(',');
    return res[num];
}
```

Or use [url.pathToFileURL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathtofileurl_path) from node's core package "url" (Added in node version v10.12.0)

Comment: What does `p` mean infront of the '../date.csv' (p'../date.csv')? I'm getting SyntaxError: Unexpected string because of the `p`

Comment: I run this script locally, is it still valid to set BASE_URL?

Comment: "What does p mean infront of the '../date.csv'" - sorry, it was a typo

Comment: "I run this script locally, is it still valid to set BASE_URL?" 

I mean, the files are in the local directory? Try assigning a value "file://path_to_root_dir" to the variable BASE_URL. However, I don't know if the 'node-fetch' supports the 'file://' protocol.

Comment: In any case, it is highly desirable to test the code under conditions as close to reality as possible. If in reality your parser.js uses the http or https protocols, it would be correct to use http or https during testing.

Comment: When I'm trying to assign the value 'file://path_to_root_dir' I'm getting `TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported`. Are there are any other ways not to use `node-fetch`?

Comment: That is, are you using this package to only read local files? In this case, of course, you are better off using fs.readFile: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback